# Null check operator used on a null value on Flutter 2.5.3

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

i´m getting the error above on flutter version 2.5.3, and **it is happening when i try to logout**. Apparently the error has something to do with the Products provider, just like the error is showing. But i´m still not able to fix it. It may also have something to do with null safety, and since i´m not very acquainted to it, i might be missig something.

```
>         The following _CastError was thrown building _InheritedProviderScope<Products?>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<Auth?>], value: Instance of 'Products',
> listening to value):
>         Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>
```

**main.dart**

```
return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Auth()),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
            update: (context, auth, previousProducts) => Products(auth.token!, auth.userId,
                previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items),
            create: (_) => Products('', '', []),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Cart()),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
            update: (context, auth, previousOrders) => Orders(auth.token!,
                previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders, auth.userId),
            create: (_) => Orders('', [], ''),
          ),
        ],
        child: Consumer<Auth>(
          builder: (context, authData, child) => MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.purple)
                  .copyWith(secondary: Colors.deepOrange),
            ),
            home: authData.isAuth ? ProductsOverviewScreen() : AuthScreen(),
            //routes
          ),
        ));
```

**auth.dart**

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String? _token;
  DateTime? _expiryDate;
  String? _userId;

  bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  }

  String get userId {
    return _userId!;
  }

  String? get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate!.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:$urlSegment?key=AIzaSyAA9PShE7c2ogk5L13kI0mgw24HKqL72Vc");
    try {
      final response = await http.post(url,
          body: json.encode({
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true
          }));
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
      _token = responseData['idToken'];
      _userId = responseData['localId'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now()
          .add(Duration(seconds: int.parse(responseData['expiresIn'])));
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    _token = null;
    _userId = null;
    _expiryDate = null;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't actually know how to fix it, but I **think** the error means `auth.token` is null, and when you do this `Products(auth.token!` it throws an error because it doesn't expect the value to be null

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

This issue was actually caused by the null check operator (`!`) added to the `non-nullable String` variable `auth.token` in your `main.dart` file, which basically promises Dart that the value of `auth.token` would never be null, and that promise was not kept because the `_token` variable in the `logout()` method in your `auth.dart` file was set to null and your `_token` is actually passed to your `token` getter that you call using `auth.token!` in your `main.dart` file.

### Solution:

You can of course easily fix this by removing the null check operator from the `auth.token` variable in your `main.dart` file and setting it to an empty `String` if it's value was equal to null, like this:

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
       create: (_) => Products('', '', []),
       update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
         auth.token ?? '',
         auth.userId ?? '',
         previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
       ),
     ),
```

you should also make your userId getter nullable like this or it would throw another error:

```
String? get userId {
  return _userId;
}
```

the `??` operator in Dart is basically an assignment operator that executes when the variable it is used for is equal to null.

And here's an extra guide from the Dart Team on working with null safety: https://dart.dev/null-safety